# Display different html depending on array string selected in slider?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've been working on a jQuery UI single slider which I intend to have show a item's details depending on which string from the array is selected. So far it shows the price of the item, but the main thing I need it to do is display different html content (it'll end up being a table, probably) depending on which step in the slider the handle is on. I've got this code so far:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var valMap = [
"1.5",
"2.5",
"5.5",
"10.5"
];
    $("#slider").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: valMap.length - 1,
        value: 0,
        animate: false,
        change: function(event, ui) {                        
            $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[ui.value] + '0');
        }       
    });
                $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[$("#slider").slider("value")] + '0');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br />
<center>
<div id="slider"></div>

<div id="planlabel"><p>
  <label for="amount">Plan:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" readonly />
</p></div>

</center>
```

I attempted to set up an "if" statement that checked the value of the 'amount' input area, but that didn't go so well (didn't work whatsoever, haha). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's an example of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/SDDJ/zHMYc/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the value of the slider in order to determine which content to show. Perhaps something like the following:-

```
<div class="content" id="content0"> ... </div>
<div class="content" id="content1"> ... </div>
<div class="content" id="content2"> ... </div>
<div class="content" id="content3"> ... </div>
```

Then just show the `div` which matches the `ui.value`, and hide the others:

```
change: function(event, ui) {                        
  $("#amount").val('$' + valMap[ui.value] + '0');
  $('#content' + ui.value).show().siblings('div.content').hide();
}
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHMYc/5/)